# I am trying to draw a polygon that connects 6 points that are clicked on the screen but it's not working

Tags: java, polygon

Could someone help me figure out what is wrong with this code? I am trying to write a Java program that uses GUI interfaces. The program is supposed to draw a polygon that connects six points that are clicked on the screen. I am so confused I can't seem to find the error anymore.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.applet.*;    
import java.net.*;      
import java.io.*;   

public class PolygonDrawer extends JFrame implements MouseListener
{


   private JLabel label;

   private ArrayList<Integer> xPoints = new ArrayList<Integer>(5); //add x values to ArrayList when clicked.
   private ArrayList<Integer> yPoints = new ArrayList<Integer>(5); //add y values to ArrayList when clicked.
   private int [] xArray = new int [5]; //copy the values from ArrayList of x values
   private int [] yArray = new int [5]; // copy the values from ArrayList of y values 
   private int count = 0; //keep count of how many times the mouse is clicked.

   public PolygonDrawer()
   {
      setTitle("Polygon Drawer with Sound");
      setSize(900,900);
      setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      setVisible(true);
      this.addMouseListener(this);


   }
   public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me)
   {

      xPoints.add(me.getX());
      yPoints.add(me.getY());
      count++;

      repaint();
   }
   public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)
   { 
   }
   public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e)
   {
   }
   public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e)
   {
   }
   public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) 
   {
   }
   public static void main (String [] args)
   {
      new PolygonDrawer();
   }
   public void paint(Graphics g)
   {
      super.paint(g);
      if(count==6)
      {
         for(int i =0 ;i<5;i++)
         {
            xArray[i]=xPoints.get(i);
            yArray[i]=yPoints.get(i);
         }

         g.fillPolygon(xArray,yArray,6);

      }



   }

}
```

Comment: You limit the amount of points in the `xPoints`, `yPoints`, `xArray` and `yArray` to 5 instead of 6. That is an issue.

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop isn't looping enough times to iterate through the entire array. It will only get the first 5 elements. As a general rule you need to increment `i` to the length of the array. So change your `for` loop to this:

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++) // 6 is the number of points so that's what you need to go to.
 {
   xArray[i]=xPoints.get(i);
   yArray[i]=yPoints.get(i);
 }
```

In addition your method of drawing is slightly wrong for swing components. You should draw as is demonstrated in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step2.html). So your complete method will look like this:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {

public MyPanel() {
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.black));
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);       
 if(count==6)
  {
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++)  {
        xArray[i]=xPoints.get(i);
        yArray[i]=yPoints.get(i);
       }
  }
    }  
}
```

In your constructor you need to add:

```
getContentPane().add(new MyPanel());
```

Before you set the frame visible to true or else it won't paint.

Comment: Thank you. I made that change but it is still not drawing anything

Comment: It is still not working. I appreciate your assistance though.

Comment: @Koolkirtzz What's happening?

Comment: Its giving me a huge error saying the arraylist is empty
I even tried to print out the values in the array but its not printing anything. Its not storing anything in the array. Is there an alternative method of doing this? I feel like my approach is wrong. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Oops, I forgot to include your if statement.

Comment: It still didn't work. Its giving me the same error. For some reason, its not storing anything into the ArrayList or the Array.

Comment: Hey I figured it out. It had to do with the numbers in the count and the for loop and also the size of the array. After playing around with those numbers it finally worked. Thanks for your help though.